# LIMIT results to n unique column values?

Tags: mysql

I have some MySQL results like this:

```
---------------------------
| name | something_random |
---------------------------
| john | ekjalsdjalfjkldd |
| alex | akjsldfjaekallee |
| alex | jkjlkjslakjfjflj |
| alex | kajslejajejjaddd |
|  bob | ekakdie33kkd93ld |
|  bob | 33kd993kakakl3ll |
| paul | 3k309dki595k3lkd |
| paul | 3k399kkfkg93lk3l |
etc...
```

This goes on for 1000's of rows of results. I need to limit the number of results to the first 50 unique names. I think there is a simple solution to this but I'm not sure.

I've tried using derived tables and variables but can't quite get there. If I could figure out how to increment a variable once every time a name is different I think I could say `WHERE variable <= 50`.

**UPDATED**

I've tried the Inner Join approach(es) suggested below. The problem is this:

The subselect `SELECT DISTINCT name FROM testTable LIMIT 50` grabs the first 50 distinct names. Perhaps I wasn't clear enough in my original post, but this limits my query too much. In my query, not every name in the table is returned in the result. Let me modify my original example:

```
----------------------------------
|   id | name | something_random |
----------------------------------
|    1 | john | ekjalsdjalfjkldd |
|    4 | alex | akjsldfjaekallee |
|    4 | alex | jkjlkjslakjfjflj |
|    4 | alex | kajslejajejjaddd |
|    6 |  bob | ekakdie33kkd93ld |
|    6 |  bob | 33kd993kakakl3ll |
|   12 | paul | 3k309dki595k3lkd |
|   12 | paul | 3k399kkfkg93lk3l |
etc...
```

So I added in some id numbers here. These ID numbers pertain to the people's names in the tables. So you can see in the results, not every single person/name in the table is necessarily in the result (due to some WHERE condition). So the 50th distinct name in the list will always have an ID number higher than 49. The 50th person could be id 79, 234, 4954 etc...

So back to the problem. The subselect `SELECT DISTINCT name FROM testTable LIMIT 50` selects the first 50 names in the table. That means that my search results will be limited to names that have ID <=50, which is too constricting. If there are certain names that don't show up in the query (due to some WHERE condition), then they are still counted as one of the 50 distinct names. So you end up with too few results.

**UPDATE 2**

To @trapper: This is a basic simplification of what my query looks like:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.name,
    t2.details
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.some_id
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM t1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 0,50) s ON s.name = t1.name
WHERE
    SOME CONDITIONS
ORDER BY
    t1.id,
    t1.name
```

And my results look like this:

```
----------------------------------
|   id | name |          details |
----------------------------------
|    1 | john | ekjalsdjalfjkldd |
|    3 | alex | akjsldfjaekallee |
|    3 | alex | jkjlkjslakjfjflj |
|    4 | alex | kajslejajejjaddd |
|    6 |  bob | ekakdie33kkd93ld |
|    6 |  bob | 33kd993kakakl3ll |
|   12 | paul | 3k309dki595k3lkd |
|   12 | paul | 3k399kkfkg93lk3l |
...
|   37 | bill | kajslejajejjaddd |
|   37 | bill | ekakdie33kkd93ld |
|   41 | matt | 33kd993kakakl3ll |
|   50 | jake | 3k309dki595k3lkd |
|   50 | jake | 3k399kkfkg93lk3l |
----------------------------------
```

The results stop at id=50. There are NOT 50 distinct names in the list. There are only roughly 23 distinct names.

Comment: LIMIT 0,50 has nothing to do with the id row. It blindly takes rows 0-50 from the entire result set and returns them. So you would get name 'jim', id '79,234,4954' quite happily as long as there wasn't more than 49 unique names ahead of him.

Comment: @trapper take a look at my second update above.

Comment: Your `WHERE` condition is probably in the wrong place, it should be inside the bracketed `SELECT` unless you are wanting to apply it to the results *after* already cutting it down to the 50 names.

Comment: Also I think you have shifted the goal posts a bit here with these additional details, your original question has been answered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My MySql syntax may be rusty, but the idea is to use a query to select the top 50 distinct names, then do a self-join on name and select the name and other information from the join.

```
select a.name, b.something_random
from Table b
    inner join (select distinct name from Table order by RAND() limit 0,50) a
         on a.name = b.name
```

Comment: I will try that approach. Is this essentially performing 2 queries? Or 2*num_of_unique_names queries? Also, why do you inner join a table with itself?

Comment: Hopefully, you have an index on name and it will result in an index scan plus an index join on the same table.  I guess you could call that 2 queries, but short of using a cursor I don't know how else you would do it.  Using a cursor could be much worse, i.e., a full table scan, depending on your data.  You would, of course, need the index on name to avoid that for the join.

Comment: @Jakobud - one potential issue with this is that you may get the top 50 alphabetical names.  If so, you might want to throw in an `Order By RAND()` - again, my syntax might need some fixing up.

Comment: This almost gets me where I want. Look at my updated post above.

Comment: @Jakobud apply the conditions to the select distinct query.  You might need to add in the ID, i.e., `select distinct id, name ...` if what you are really after 50 random people instead of 50 random names.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM table LIMIT 0,50
```

Edited: Ahh yes I misread question first time, this should do the trick though :)

```
SELECT a.name, b.something_random
FROM `table` b
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,50) a
     ON a.name = b.name ORDER BY a.name
```

How this work is the `(SELECT DISTINCT name FROM`table`ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,50)` part is what pulls out the names to include in the join. So here I am taking 50 unique names at random, but you can change this to any other selection criteria if you want.

Then you join those results back into your table. This links each of those 50 selected names back to all of the rows with a matching name for your final results. Finally `ORDER BY a.name` just to be sure all the rows for each name end up grouped together.

Comment: All that seems to do is limit the results to 50 rows. I think you misunderstood my question. The number of returned rows is arbitrary. I just need to limit the results to the first 50 distinct names. The number of returned rows could potentially be any number > 50.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT tA.*
FROM
    testTable tA
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT distinct name FROM testTable LIMIT 50) tB ON tA.name = tB.name
;
```

Comment: As noted in tvanfosson's similar answer, the select in the subquery might want to be ordered in some way (or by RAND()) to get the results you want.